# Can multiple apps share a single instance of an IBM Graph service?

Tags: ibm-cloud, graph-databases, ibm-graph

I have an instance of [IBM Graph](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/ibm-graph/) I need to write data and query it from multiple applications. Do I need to bind my apps to my instance or do I need to create a separate instance for each app? Ideally, I'd like to share my data between all of my applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can share your instance between all of your applications. You don't need to bind your app to the instance, but you can if you want. When you instantiate an [IBM Graph](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/ibm-graph/) instance you get back a set of credentials and a url similar to this

`{
    "credentials": {
    "apiURL": "https://graphrestify-alpha.ng.bluemix.net/2208V...348/g",
    "username": "a530...dba",
    "password": "ab7c...327"
  }
}`

Your app(s) will be using the `apiURL` together with the username:password combination to issue queries against the service. For example, one application can send a `/vertices` request to create a vertex and another application can be doing a `/gremlin` request (gremlin query) to the same graph at the same time. Both applications can be both producers and consumers of data.